# dired: copy a symlink'd file

Tags: dired

`dired-do-copy` copies a symlink as a symlink.
Sometimes I want to copy the actual file of a symlink,
not make a copy of the symlink.
Is there already a way to do that?
I can write some elisp code but seems this must be already builtin to dired.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can see.

You could use: <kbd>!</kbd> `cp -L ? <newname>` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you want to roll your own, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `file-truename` is the elisp function that chases symlinks to return the fully-dereferenced file name.